# Fetching id from database of submitted data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, database

So I am submitting data to the database. Each data sent contains an id that is auto incremented. With ajax or PHP (I am very much new to this, and trying to learn I'm sure it's ajax along with some php) I need to fetch the id of the data that was submitted.

The idea is, after the form is submitted, the user gets the link back to the submitted page. Example:

> Quote was submitted! [link] Click to go to the link or go back.

The link will look like this: http://example.com/quote-192
I pretty much have everything else set, I just don't know how I'll get the id and add it to the link.

Here is the PHP that processes the form:

```
require('inc/connect.php');


    $quote = $_POST['quote'];
    $quotes = mysql_real_escape_string($quote);

    //echo $quotes . "Added to database";

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO entries (quote) VALUES('$quotes')")
    or die(mysql_error());
```

Oh, and the data is being sent with ajax:

```
 $(document).delegate("'#submit-quote'", "submit", function(){
        var quoteVal = $(this).find('[name="quote"]').val();
        $.post("add.php", $(this).serialize(), function() {
            var like = $('.quote-wrap span iframe');
            $('.inner').prepend('<div class="quote-wrap group">' + like + '<div class="quote"><p>' + quoteVal+ '</p></div></div>');
            // console.log("success");

        });
        return false;
    });
```

So how would I get the id for each quote and add it to the page after the form has been submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you php:

```
echo mysql_insert_id($result)
```

Then in your jquery ajax:

```
$.ajax({
type:'post',
url:'url.php',
data:querystring,
success:function(data){
  var id = parseInt(data);
}
]);
```

this will return the inserted ID as an integer value that you can work with in javascript

Comment: I am really new to ajax. How can I work this in the code I am using?

Comment: The way I wrote it is the long form way of doing the jQuery. You can just add your serialize statement into where I have 'querystring' and add your callback into where the success function is. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ Read through this and see if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

With this php-function. You can call after inserting.

```
int mysql_insert_id ([ resource $Verbindungs-Kennung ] )
```

[`mysql_insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-insert-id.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have the PHP print the ID as a response to the request:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO entries (quote) VALUES('$quotes')")
    or die(mysql_error());

// Print the id of last insert as a response
echo mysql_insert_id();
```

jQuery, test code to alert what was echoed by the PHP as a test

```
// add data as a param to the function to have access to the PHP response    

$.post("add.php", $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
  alert(data);
});
```

Comment: edit: when I alert, I get NaN with parseInt. If I don't use parseInt then the alert shows a bunch of messed up HTML..... showing PHP giving an error .